# Filter by certain pattern in all CharField in Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I got a serach box in my project, the thing is that a user can enter any keyword and my ModelForm filters the fields I explicitly tell to filter, I use the following piece of code in my Form:

```
def get_matching_siniestros(self):
    if self.cleaned_data['keywords'] is None:
        return None
    matching = []
    for kw in self.cleaned_data['keywords']:
        numero_ajuste = Siniestro.objects.filter(
            numero_ajuste__icontains=kw
        )

        nombre_contratante = Siniestro.objects.filter(
            poliza__contratante__nombre__icontains=kw
        )


        matching = chain(
            numero_ajuste, 
            nombre_contratante,
            matching
        )

    # verify not repeated Siniestro
    non_rep_siniestros = []
    for siniestro in matching:
        if siniestro not in non_rep_siniestros:
            non_rep_siniestros.append(siniestro)

    return non_rep_siniestros
```

What I want to do is to programatically filter on any CharField in the Model and also if possible on any CharField of nested relations, in this example Siniestro has a FK to poliza and poliza has an FK to contratante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over every field and do whatever you like, e.g.:

```
[process(field) for field in model._meta.fields if field.__class__ == CharField]
```

where process can be a function, or whatever you require.

That said, I should really point out that the complexity you're trying to involve is bound to get messy. IMO, have a look at [django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/). Indexing should be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the proper answer, on the other hand, I know my way of working this thing is not even remotely appropiate, I actually use SOLR.